# Android SendKey method

Tags: android, android-activity, background, sendkeys

Is there any way to send keys or characters to another program activities ? something like [C# SendKey method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method :

```
private String key;



   @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
     Log.i("Key pressed was : ", String.valueOf(event.getKeyCode()));
     key = String.valueof(event.getKeyCode());
     return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Then using an `Intent` you can send the value to another Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("keyString, key);
```

And retrieve it in your other Activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String key = intent.getStringExtra("keyString");
```

EDIT:
[On this site someone solved this problem (sending key events to an external activity)](http://www.pocketmagic.net/injecting-events-programatically-on-android/#.Ui81ddyg2f0)

Comment: no i want to send this keys to other programs not my programs

Comment: Ok , but using Android API (official and internal) the OS forbids sending key events to activities of other apps. However, you can do it at Linux OS level. For this to work, you will need root access, though.   Check my edit answer for link , someone solved this.